# Regarding QT creator in Lubuntu 16.04 (i386) ICOP board

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, embedded-linux, sse2

I have installed qtcreator in lubuntu 16.04 and when trying to open it, i am getting an error

> This program requires an x86 processor that supports SSE2 extension, at least a Pentium 4 or newer
>   Aborted (core dumped)

can someone help me to solve this problem.

I'm using ICOP borad with Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: @eyllanesc yes i have installed qtcreator (3.5.1) based on QT 5.5.1, but when i try opening it i'm getting the above error.

Comment: I have not asked you if you have it installed but what was your installation procedure

Comment: I used following commands to install
`sudo apt-get install build-essential`
`sudo apt-get install qtcreator`
`sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

Comment: mmm, if so it is better that you report it as a bug to Lubuntu. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2308366

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to compile from source with `-mno-sse` (Or just `-mno-sse2` if your CPU has SSE1 but not SSE2).  If you're not cross-compiling from a faster machine, use `-march=native` to enable all the instruction sets your CPU supports, and *not* enable any that it doesn't.)

The 32-bit qtcreator package probably enables SSE2 on purpose, because detected it and printed an error instead of just dying with a SIGILL.  Likely it can be built from source (or the Ubuntu source package) with a different config.

---

**Apparently 32-bit Ubuntu is intended to run on CPUs without SSE2**, according to [this guide posted in the Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640&s=577ce4c5342782fa8e1e426017746243&p=12565189#post12565189).  (It's talking about old desktops with old mainstream CPUs, not modern embedded, but same difference.)  So this might be considered a bug.

gcc's 32-bit code-gen does default to assuming `cmov` support and other P6 (Pentium Pro / Pentium II) instructions, but I guess Ubuntu configures their 32-bit gcc to not enable `-msse2` by default.  So you couldn't even boot the kernel on a P5 Pentium or older.  (Makes sense, if you have SSE2 you probably have an x86-64 capable CPU; running on 32-bit-only CPUs is one of the few reasons for not just using x86-64 Ubuntu.  But some people do use 32-bit systems for some reason on modern HW, and gimping it too much by disabling `cmov` and other P6 new instructions might be undesirable.)

A few years ago (like 2013 maybe?) I booted an Ubuntu live CD on an Athlon XP (SSE1 but not SSE2).  It mostly booted to the desktop, but there was a popup from one program that it had died with SIGILL.  i.e. it tried to run an SSE2 instruction and got an illegal-instruction exception.  I guess this would be considered a but if 32-bit Ubuntu really does aim to support CPUs without SSE2